# Correct way to customise widget font, colour and background with GtkStyleProviders

Tags: css, fonts, colors, gtk, styling

In trying to clean up some warnings about deprecation `Gtk.Widget.modify_base`,`Gtk.Widget.modify_font` , I found the suggested replacements, `override_background_color` (and the equivalents for font and colour) are *also* deprecated. I am now trying to work out how to provide these styles to the widgets.

The font, colour and background are for a custom `TextView` widget and the values for these are stored in some strings as part of some preferences, so that the user can customise colours for several different things.

For the font and text colour, it seems that the best way might be to create `Gtk.TextTag`s with the appropriate styling, and change any instances of `insert()` on the text buffer to `insert_with_tags()`. There doesn't seem to be a "default style" concept for TextBuffers and TextTags.

However, text tags won't deal with the background for the whole text view.

The suggested approach appears to be `GtkStyleProvider`, but how should I go about feeding these user-specified colours into the provider?

Lots of examples load string constants like this:

```
string style = """
    GtkButton {color:#ff00ea; font:Serif 12;}
    GtkButton:hover {background-color:#3085a9;}
    GtkLabel {background-color:#898989;}
    GtkEntry {background-color:green; color:red;}
""";
CssProvider provider = new CssProvider();
provider.load_from_data(style,-1);
```

But in this case, I'll have to manually format and interpolate the strings into a big block of CSS each time the config changes and feed it back into the style, which seems pretty messy. I'm also not sure if these can be changed after loading, as there doesn't seem to be a changed signal.

I suppose the other way is to somehow inherit `GtkStyleProvider` and implement my own, but this seems overkill for setting a handful of colours, and there appears to be very little documentation for it.

Most GTK+ programs (even GNOME ones) seem to just do it the "old" way with `modify_*` and `override_*` and ignore the deprecations, and it's not clear to me if the few that do use CSS can change it after load.

Are these the only two options? And which one is "right"?